# Rails find by condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just wondering if there is any function that allows to do that:

```
MyModel.find_by_conditon(method_a - method_b > 0)
```

`MyModel.class`

```
def method_a
  next_service_date.to_i
end

def method_b
  last_service_date.to_i
end
```

```
def next_service_date
  service_date.present? ? calculated_time_estimation : row_time_estimation
end
def calculated_time_estimation
  service_date + calculated_service_period
end
def calculated_service_period
      case(service_frequency_period)
      when 'Year'
        service_frequency_number.to_i.year
      when 'Month'
        service_frequency_number.to_i.month
      when 'Week'
        service_frequency_number.to_i.day * 7
      when 'Day'
        service_frequency_number.to_i.day
      end
end
```

`service_frequency_number`, `service_frequency_period`, `service_date` are attributes for MyModel

Comment: Can you give a better idea of what problem your are trying to solve? The question and the definitions are a bit vague.

Is last_service_date equivalent to service_date ? Also how is row_time_estimate defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `method_a` and `method_b` are actually attributes, you can do:

```
MyModel.where('method_a - method_b > ?', 0)
```

**Edit**

I think the only way that you're going to be able to query on a calculated field is to move the calculation to the DB, where you would have a scalar function to return the results.  Then you could do `MyModel.where('next_service_date_on_db(service_date) > 0')`.  Unfortunately, that would tie you to a DB-specific implementation, but you're not going to be able to query that way without a server-side function.

Now, if you have the entire collection, you could filter based on those conditions, but you'll have to load the entire set.  For example:

```
MyModel.all.select {|m| m.method_a - m.method_b > 0}
```

`#all` returns an array of all of the objects, and select filters based on the condition of the block.  Unfortunately, this solution loads all of the records to sort application side.

Comment: Unfortunately method_a and method_b are not attrubutes, just have updated a question

Comment: Is `next_service_date` an attribute?

Comment: @SeanHill Ah, I hadn't refreshed my page in a while. I removed my answer since you're saying the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve .. but you may have to resort to SQL?

(and what's method_a and b?)

```
MyModel.where('? > 0', (method_a - method_b))
```

Comment: How would this work?  `method_a` and `method_b` are instance methods on `MyModel`.

Comment: I was under the impression that method_a and method_b returned some sort of integer that when combined .. would be used to compare against "greater than 0".